# How does Expr_if is reformulated in pyomo fo solver?

Tags: pyomo

I came across Expr_if in pyomo that can do logical if-then-else with variables. Here is dummy example.

```
model = ConcreteModel()

# Define variables
model.x = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
model.y = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
model.condition = Var(within=Binary)  # This is a binary variable to control the if condition

# If condition == 1, then x <= y; otherwise, x <= 5
model.conditional_constraint = Constraint(expr=model.x <= Expr_if(model.condition, y, 5))

# Objective function to minimize
model.obj = Objective(expr=model.x + model.y)

# Solve the model
solver = SolverFactory('bonmin')
# solver = SolverFactory('baron')
solver.solve(model)
```

I understand Expr_if needs to be reformulated before passing it to the solver. How does pyomo reformulate it? It seems it's reformulating it as nonlinear constraints because it can't write this model to *.lp with error *Cannot write legal LP file.  Constraint 'conditional_constraint' has a body with nonlinear terms.*

Is there a way to force pyomo to reformulate it using binary variables? I don't want to make my LP into NLP. Also, I don't want to manually reformulate.

**Note:** When I export it to .gams, the cosntraint is written as
`c1_hi.. x1 - Expr_if( ( condition ), then=( 10 ), else=( 5 ) ) =l= 0 ;` How does GAMS reformulate it?

Comment: You just need to reformulate this into a big-M constraint.  But first, you'd need to fix the other logic in your model.  Right now, the optimal solution is just x=0, y=0 because it is minimization.  If you flip this to a maximization, you'll need some "reasonable upper bound" on x, y to make big-M work

Comment: Thank you. Apology, I meant ```If condition == 1, then x <= y; otherwise, x <= 5``` This is just a dummy problem to illustrate. yes, I can formulate it using big M but was wondering, can Expr_if do it for me.

Comment: Currently, it seems it uses something like: ```x <= y*condition + 5*(1-condition)``` I am guessing it, as I see using Expr_if converts linear problem (MILP) into nonlinear problem (MINLP).